# Is there a way to disable one wireless adapter if any other is present?

Tags: wireless, hardware

Title's pretty specific, but...

I have an Intel WLAN A/G/N card that came with the laptop internally.  I have a Netgear USB  dongle I use for my wifi on occasion, and it works better than the card on my system.  Is there a way to tell the system to automatically disable the Intel wifi adapter and enable the Netgear adapter if it's present?

And to expand this, is it possible to configure the system to disable the Intel card if *any* other wireless adapter is present?

A guide to what to do would be helpful, because this is something I haven't worked with before...

Answer (score 0):

[Write a udev rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) that, upon insertion of a WLAN device (hint: kernel name of "wlan*", "ath*", or various others) [unbinds the Intel Wifi card from its driver](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/).